# Magento 2 Google Universal Analytics code

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

In a Magento 2.1.2 store under **Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Google Api** I entered the Google Analytics code. After a couple of days I noticed no information coming in and my customer had a mail from Google saying the URL was no longer valid for the Merchant account.

I found that my customer had a `Universal Analytics code` (compared to the "old analytics code" and that Google demands it to be within the `< head >` tags whereas Magento 2.1.2 places it within the `< body >` tag. This Universal Analytics code has been around for 4 years and even with the old code it was recommended to place it within the `< head >` tags.

My question is, why is it that even in Magento 2 the Google Analytics code is placed within the body tags? Is there a good reason for it or am I missing something?

Comment: use the reference of google analytics section and move it to head section in your module xml file

Comment: It needs to be in the head section, not sure why Magento has not following GA guidelines. If you are looking for UA with Enhanced Ecommerce then the following module will help solve your problem https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento2-google-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html

Answer (score 6):

I hope you have found the answer to it, if not here is a simplest solution to it

In you theme add directory `Magento_GoogleAnalytics > layout`.

> Magento_GoogleAnalytics is **Google Analytics** module by Magento team.

It will then look like this

`<MagentoBase>/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_GoogleAnalytics/layout`

then create a layout file `default.xml` on above path

It will finally look like this

`<MagentoBase>/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_GoogleAnalytics/layout/default.xml`

Place the code in default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="google_analytics" destination="head.additional"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the above code we are moving the google analytics section in head using -

```
<move element="google_analytics" destination="head.additional"/>
```

Hope others looking for this find it useful.